ts-node-dev doesn't support ts requires in js
I'm trying to import ts. files inside a .js file (reason is that I don't have time to fully migrate my project to typescript)
I figured out a way like that :
I have my routes.ts that I want to import in my index.js, my routes.ts has all types needed.
routes.ts :
import { Express, Request, Response, Router } from 'express';

const routes = (app: Express) => {
  const router = Router({ mergeParams: true });

  router.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response) =>
    res.status(404).json(`${req?.originalUrl} can't be find !`),
  );

  app.use('/', router);
};

export default routes;


in my index.js, I add those lines :
...
require('ts-node/register');
require('tsconfig-paths/register');
...
// eslint-disable-next-line node/no-missing-require
const router = require('./routes').default;
...

now I'm able without problem to build and deploy using yarn build:
"build": "yarn tsc && tsc-alias",

but suddenly, when I want to yarn dev:
"dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register --respawn --transpile-only bin/www/index.js",

it gives me error types, but not common error types, it's giving me error types on a routes.ts that seem to have been transpiled to routes.js (the behavior I actually want), but it also seems that ts-node-dev still keeps the behavior as if the file was still a routes.ts which is why it's giving types errors. I don't know if I'm clear here but here is the output so you can compare with the routes.ts code snippet I gave earlier :
yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.22
$ ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register --respawn --transpile-only bin/www/index.js
[INFO] 11:01:09 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.9.2, typescript ver. 5.4.5)
[ERROR] 11:01:10 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/routes.ts:2:32 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

2 var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
                                 ~~~~
src/routes.ts:2:67 - error TS7006: Parameter 'mod' implicitly has an 'any' type.

2 var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
                                                                    ~~~
src/routes.ts:15:17 - error TS7006: Parameter 'app' implicitly has an 'any' type.

15 const routes = (app) => {
                   ~~~
src/routes.ts:24:22 - error TS7006: Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.

24     router.all('*', (req, res) => res.status(404).json(`${req?.originalUrl} can't be find !`));
                        ~~~
src/routes.ts:24:27 - error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.

24     router.all('*', (req, res) => res.status(404).json(`${req?.originalUrl} can't be find !`));

does anyone have any idea why is does that, I think it's a behavior with the current .default on the require and perhaps ts-node-dev is struggling?
